# Where should I put new Modules for rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to create a personalized module, for my controller I have read that I have to put in the **lib folder**  inside my l**ib folder** I have *assets and tasks folder*s, so where so should I put my modules and how can I use them in a specific controller

Comment: you can add it in lib folder directly.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new folder inside app/ since the app/ folder is autoloaded. lib/ is not. If you put it into lib, you will have to restart the server every time you make changes to it.

Comment: I would agree with @SiimLiiser on this one. Simply create a folder inside your app folder, so it looks like `app/yourmodulename`. You can then do whatever you want with it - include it in `AppController` or something similar

Comment: @mutantkeyboard `app/modules/yourmodulename.rb` or `app/mixins/yourmodulename.rb` or similar. Whatever describes the modules best, but not yourmodulename as the folder.

Comment: @SiimLiiser that's what I meant :) - typo